# How to get report of "those users who were excluded" using multiple where-object conditions in get-aduser command?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have put together a script which uses the `get-aduser` command in ActiveDirectory module to fetch report of users who have logged in since last 30 days. The script also excludes users based on certain parameters which are specified beforehand in an array list (for example, exclude users with description 'admin', ' test' etc). I have included the code as well.

The report works OK without any issues.
Now, is there a way to get a report of those users who were excluded as part of these filters?
I know the script can be re-run by reversing the -nomatch switches to -match and few other adjusts to get the desired data - but is there a better, cleaner way ???  See code below:

```
import-module activedirectory
$excludeOU = @("service accounts","exchange accounts","monitoring mailboxes","Test","Support Users")
$excludedescription = @("admin","logistik","test","serviceaccount","service account","Anonymous","logistics","logistiek","gen_","automation")
$excludesam = @("adm-","support","service","install","invoice","floor","svc-","sa-","gen_","alg_","dev.ops")
$excludefirstname = @("Gateway")

get-aduser -filter * -properties whencreated, lastlogondate, description, telephonenumber, city, country, title, department, company, manager, mail, displayname | 
Where-Object {($_.lastlogondate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and ($_.distinguishedname -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludeOU) + ')')) -and ($_.enabled -eq "TRUE") -and ($_.description -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludedescription) + ')')) -and ($_.givenname -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludefirstname) + ')')) -and ($_.samaccountname -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludesam) + ')'))} | 
select-object givenname, surname, whencreated, description, lastlogondate, telephonenumber, city, country, title, department, company, @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -properties displayname).displayname}}, samaccountname, mail, displayname, userprincipalname, @{Name='OU';Expression={$_.distinguishedname -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}}, enabled | 
export-csv C:\ADreporter\powershell\report_$(Get-Date -UFormat “%B-%d-%Y”).csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Please use code formatting in your question (indent 4 spaces).

Comment: It's a one line command piped together with several conditions.

Comment: That script should not _work OK_, because in your extremely long `Where-Object` clause, you systematically forget the underscore. (`$.lastlogondate` --> `$_.lastlogondate` etc. etc. etc.)

Comment: My usual way of dealing with this kind of situation is to output everything to a CSV file (or similar) and use spreadsheet filtering (or a database query, for large data sets) after the fact. In this way you have _all_ the data and you can answer these kinds of questions more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Programming/formatting style ***IS*** as matter of presonal prefernces,
but the way you do it in your script renders it nearly **un**readable.

- You know that you can insert line breaks where ever PowerShell expects a continuation?
  That is after a `|{,`,operators `-and` or in front of a `}` or explicitly after a single backtick **>`<**
- constructing the RegEx Alternation inside that monstruous `Where-Object` is **not** helpful
  why not doing that just after defining the arrays?
- IMO obeying the camel type notation of cmdlets/parameters helps reading; but that's debatable.

---

I applied some of that to your script for better readability:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\23\SO_57627751.ps1
Import-Module activedirectory

$excludeOU = @("service accounts","exchange accounts","monitoring mailboxes","Test","Support Users")

$excludedescription = @("admin","logistik","test","serviceaccount","service account",
                        "Anonymous","logistics","logistiek","gen_","automation")

$excludesam = @("adm-","support","service","install","invoice","floor",
                "svc-","sa-","gen_","alg_","dev.ops")

$excludefirstname = @("Gateway")

Get-ADUser -filter * -properties whencreated, lastlogondate, description, telephonenumber, 
               city, country, title, department, company, manager, mail, displayname | 
  Where-Object {($_.lastlogondate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and 
                ($_.distinguishedname -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludeOU) + ')')) -and 
                ($_.enabled -eq "TRUE") -and 
                ($_.description -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludedescription) + ')')) -and 
                ($_.givenname -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludefirstname) + ')')) -and 
                ($_.samaccountname -notmatch ('(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $excludesam) + ')'))} | 
  Select-Object givenname, surname, whencreated, description, lastlogondate, 
                telephonenumber, city, country, title, department, company, 
               @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -properties displayname).displayname}}, 
               samaccountname, mail, displayname, userprincipalname, 
               @{Name='OU';Expression={$_.distinguishedname -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}}, enabled |
  Export-Csv C:\ADreporter\powershell\report_$(Get-Date -UFormat “%B-%d-%Y”).csv -NoTypeInformation
```

## but is there a better, cleaner way ?

Store your first `Get-ADUser` output in a variable, apply your `Where-Object` on it and 
store the result in another variable to then use `Compare-Object` on them.

Depending on the size of your AD there might be other better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to create a custom helper function to do all testing on the user's properties and use that in the `Where-Object` clause.

For efficiency, it exits with `$false` on the first test that fails, and therefore all tests are 'reversed'.
(`-notmatch` --> `-match`, `-ge` --> `-lt`).
Also, on the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet itself, I've added `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'` so we don't have to deal with disabled users at least..

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Test-User {
    # a dedicated helper function to test several properties of a user object
    # returns $true or $false. Bails out with $false on the first failed test.
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]$User
    )
    # test LastLogonDate
    if ($User.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) { return $false }

    # test DistinghuishedName
    $exclude = '({0})' -f ('service accounts','exchange accounts',
                           'monitoring mailboxes','Test','Support Users' -join '|')
    if ($User.DistinguishedName -match $exclude) { return $false }

    # test Description
    $exclude = '({0})' -f ('admin','logistik','test','serviceaccount','service account',
                           'Anonymous','logistics','logistiek','gen_','automation' -join '|')
    if ($User.Description -match $exclude) { return $false }

    # test firstname
    $exclude = '({0})' -f (@('Gateway') -join '|')  # add more firstnames if needed
    if ($User.GivenName -match $exclude) { return $false }

    # test SamAccountName
    $exclude = '({0})' -f ('adm-','support','service','install','invoice',
                           'floor','svc-','sa-','gen_','alg_','dev.ops' -join '|')
    if ($User.SamAccountName -match $exclude) { return $false }

    # if you've come this far, the user object passed all tests
    return $true
}

$properties = 'Created', 'LastLogonDate', 'Description', 'telephoneNumber', 'City', 
              'Country', 'Title', 'Department', 'Company', 'Manager', 'EmailAddress', 'DisplayName'
$outputFile = 'C:\ADreporter\powershell\report_{0:MMMM-d-yyyy}.csv' -f (Get-Date)

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -Properties $properties | 
    Where-Object { (Test-User -User $_) } | 
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Created, Description, LastLogonDate, telephoneNumber, 
                  City, Country, Title, Department, Company,
                  @{Name='Manager'; Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName}},
                  SamAccountName, EmailAddress, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName,
                  @{Name='OU'; Expression={$_.DistinguishedName -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}},
                  Enabled |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

IMO this code reads a lot nicer than using a Where clause that never seems to end..